# Add alternate tag to individual pages in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, meta, liferay-ide

I want to add a meta tag in my each individual page of life ray. I am could only find meta tag with description which is in the SEO of the pages in Control panel.

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/xyz/abc" hreflang="en-au" />
```

Please help me out with this. I am unable to find an answer to this.

Comment: You can add it in theme template.

Comment: I really new in liferay, can you please tell me how can I add it to theme with steps

Comment: Which version of liferay are you using?

Comment: Did you find any other suitable solution?

Answer (score 0):

The best and permanent way is to create custom theme (or modify default one) and add general meta-tags, javascript / css files (which you want to appear on each page of portal) through head section of theme's `portal_normal.vm` file. However, if you want to restrict these tags for specific page(s) you can still do it through [Velocity Objects](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+Objects+from+Velocity) like public / private layout, admin / user difference, current page name / URL, there are numerous options available.

If you are new to theme design, you can start with: [Creating Liferay Themes](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-them-7)

The other possible and quick way is to add js / css dynamically using javascript / jQuery as following:

if you are using pure javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js");
    loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js");
    loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css");
}
```

Or you can use jQuery:

```
jQuery(function(){
    loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js");
    loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js");
    loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css");
});
```

general method:

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if (filetype=="css"){
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
```

Reference: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Add above code to the javascript section of the root of your pages.